# How can get rid of the oracleCommand error?

Tags: c#, oracle

How can get rid of the oracleCommand error when I put double quotation marks between "USER1"
I need to use below query for my oracleCommand and USER1 has double quotation marks and C# thinks my command only USER1, but it actually  "Select....."USER1".......dual".

```
 using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( REPLACE ( dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('PROCEDURE', 'HELL_'), '"USER1".'),'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') FROM dual", conn2))
```

**how can I modify like below**

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( REPLACE ( dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('PROCEDURE', '+ Items +'), '"" + txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper() + "".'),'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') FROM dual", conn1))
```

Comment: Why are you using double quotes?  You don't even show what the error message is.

Comment: You can use a verbatim as given in the answer or you can escape the double quotes like \"User1\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "@" to handle [Verbatim String Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), like the following:

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( REPLACE ( dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('PROCEDURE', 'HELL_'), '""USER1"".'),'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') FROM dual", conn2))
```

Comment: You should mention what "@" does.

Comment: When @ precedes a string then no attempt is made to interpret the characters in the string, such as escaped characters like `\t`, the only exception being a repeated double-quote "" which is interpreted as a single double-quote ".